# I'm trying to write the definition of functions only using logical symbols

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to write the definitions of the following functions

1. ${n} \% {k} = {p}$ iff
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ iff
3. $(X, <<)$ is a poset. An element p is a maximal element of (X, <<) iff

What I tried,

For #1, 
since p is ther remainder of the division of n with k,

$$\forall{n}∈\mathbb{R}(\exists{k, p}∈\mathbb{R}(n | k = p))$$

For #2, The definition for a converging series is,
$$\forall{\epsilon} > 0(\exists{N}∈\mathbb{N}(\forall{n}∈\mathbb{N}(n \geq N \Rightarrow |a_n - L| < \epsilon)))$$

For #3, The maximal element has to be the one on top
$$\forall{n}∈ X(\exists{x}∈X(x \geq n))$$

I'm not sure if my definitions are correct

Comment: 1 and 3 are wrong. 2 is right except that $\exists N\in N$ is silly, but presumably your intent is $\exists N\in\mathbb N$. You can use `\mathbb{N}` to get the blackboard N, but without that you should have just used a different variable name. For 1, you are binding the variables you're supposed to be talking about. For 3, you simply don't talk about $p$ at all. If I wanted to say $P$ is a predicate representing the numbers less than $10$, I might write $P(n)\equiv n<10$. I wouldn't write $\forall n.n<10$. This is the same as $\forall k.k<10$, i.e. it is independent of $n$.

Comment: For part 1, how about something like $\forall{n}∈\mathbb{R}(\exists{k, m}∈\mathbb{R}( m = n / k; p = m * n + 1 ))}$

Comment: If I wrote "$x$ is even iff $\forall n\in \mathbb N.\exists m\in\mathbb N.n = 2m$" would you consider that a correct definition of $x$ being even?